# Barcode Scanning steps and issues

Tags: c#, barcode-scanner

I am having a little problem and hope you can direct me in right way. 
I have developed an inventory system for my shoe shop few months ago.
 This has to select shoe name and some textboxes to input
catlougue number 
Qty 
Unit Price 
and total price values.

Basically I have to input all values and make the sale.

Now I have bought a barcode scanner and I want to know how to use the barcode scanner to get the values to textboxes when I scan.

I will be more greateful if someone can send me the steps of doing that.

I assume that I have to create a database for the products and create barcode. 
But I dont know how I can create barcode.

Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: the barCodeReader will generate a <code> like let's say `"QR897V"` I assume that you have to create any sort of database that links all the available codes to the other informations "Qty, price ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are fonts that produce barcodes.  Also there are jpeg and gif producing libraries.

For testing you can use this website.   http://www.barcoding.com/upc/

Your scanner will often act as a keyboard.  When it scans the complete barcode it will type in 12345 at your current point.

Use Notepad to test and play with your scanner.  Be Aware the Enter Key may be implied with some scanners and barcodes.

However...

It sounds like you are re-inventing the wheel.  It would be fun, but I would not bet my business on something that I can get an already built system to do for me.

Look at a schema for an accounting system like GP Great Plains and you will start to see the real world complexity of what you are trying to do.

Additional Note:  Just install a barcode font.  It is like Arial or Times New Roman, it is just a font.  Please get your font from an extremely trusted source.  Fonts are a very common way that malware and viruses can get into a system since the Fonts have the ability to interact with the system at its most primitive levels within the user session.

Comment: Hi,Thank you for your reply. 
can you please tell me how to give values to barcodes. 
Say I have so many products with different catlogue numbers,
each cat number displays different price. 
how can I display them in textboxes? Thanks